# Getting mysql to ignore where condition

Tags: mysql

Is there to make mysql ignore conditions if a variable isn't set, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id = $id
AND bar = $baz
```

If $baz is set run query as normal, else run the query minus the AND clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id = $id
AND ( bar = $baz OR $baz [equals null, empty string, zero, whatever] )
```

I don't know if MySQL ever uses [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in its execution plan, but it may be beneficial to put the cheaper comparison first, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id = $id
AND ( $baz [equals null, empty string, zero, whatever] OR bar = $baz )
```

You can use this methodology with multiple parameters.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id = $id
AND ( $baz [equals null, empty string, zero, whatever] OR bar = $baz )
AND ( $x = 0 or x = $x )
AND ( $y IS NULL OR y = $y )

-- etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$q = "SELECT ... id=$id "
if ($baz)
  $q .= " AND bar = $baz";
```

I assume these are PHP variables?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a variable $ignoreWhere and write it as:

SELECT * FROM foo WHERE $ignoreWhere = 1 OR id = $id

Set it to 1 to ignore the rest of the statement.

Comment: that's how I understood the question in the first place, but I guess he wants to have AND bar ... ignored, not id =

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim Medora. Your solution worked.
I was not clear at first, but when I used it worked.
So here is the story
If you use following, it is acts like skiping the AND section when $y is Null.

```
AND ( $y IS NULL OR y = $y )
```

If $y is null, then it means it is

```
AND( TRUE or y=$y)
```

which means

```
AND TRUE
```

So this means the AND section has no effect on rest of WHERE clause. In other word, it is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You add a condition that is actually a condition on your variable, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE $baz is not null -- this condition tests if $baz is set
AND (
    ... -- all "normal" conditions, including any involving $baz
)
```

If `$baz` is not set, all other conditions are bypassed

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev It is impossible for `$baz` to be `null`. If it were `null`, OP's condition `AND bar = $baz` would **not** be true (`null` is not considered equal to `null` is SQL). If he wanted to test for `null`, he would need the syntax `AND bar IS NULL`, which requires a different query.