# MySQL to ignore the column value while fetching

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets just say, I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar=$bar
```

How may I pass a value that makes it completely ignore the condition and return the rows whatever the value `bar` contains?

I have already found [Getting mysql to ignore where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631000/getting-mysql-to-ignore-where-condition) but I'd have to modify tons of queries to do so, so I was wondering if there is any easier way.

P.S `bar` and `$bar` are integers

Comment: just add or true to your where: like this `WHERE bar=$bar or true`

Comment: Why do that? I.e. first add `WHERE` and then trying to bypass it?

Comment: Just pass the fieldname `bar` itself in $bar

Comment: @AlmaDo there is the data of several companies stored in the table. Currently, it is being accessed through the company id. Now, after the requirements change, I have to create an account for the super user who can access each and every company data, that's why I need this "value"

Comment: those are already return queries which are working fine for individual companies. If you add or condition like `bar = $bar or 1=1` then everyone gets all values If you keep And `1=1 AND bar = $bar` then it is same as without AND condition. So if you want to use same code for both create **where condition dynamically**

Comment: Why can't you do this, whever you are running this SQL, you will have th info whether it's accessed by the super user or by a regular user, so simply do this:

$sql = "select * from foo ";
if($user != "superUser")
   $sql = $sql + " where bar={$bar}"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a string field.

You *could* change it to:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar like $bar
```

Then set $bar to %

There will be a performance hit with this though!

It will work with integers if you put them in quotes:

```
select * from  sites where siteid like '4037';
```

To get everything then:

```
select * from  sites where siteid like '%';
```

Would be better to rewrite the query though IMHO

Comment: `$bar` is int. Then, passing just %` there will result in error. Finally, compare int with string is bad idea

Comment: It will work with integers but you will have to put them in quotes, and take another perf hit.

Comment: So, first, you should add quotes. Next, again, it's a bad idea to rely on implicit typecasting

Comment: Agree, but AFAIK there is no other way of having a "Trigger value" that will return all rows. I think the OP should rewrite the query. Otherwise there will be perf hits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. You want to use a `WHERE` clause, but ignore it in the returned data? Just leave off the clause entirely:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

Comment: Well, `$bar` is integer, so I doubt. (and I doubt there is a way to do the trick if it's integer)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: OP said _"P.S bar and $bar are integers"_ - thus, you can't pass `OR 1` to `$bar`

Comment: But the `OR 1` clause has nothing to do with the field conditions before it? It simply causes the `WHERE` clause to return true regardless of `$bar`. If `bar` == `$bar`, it returns `true`, otherwise it'll return `1`...

Comment: If you'll just add `OR 1` into query itself, you'll break logic when `$bar` is someone different from that magic value, which OP wants to find. And that's my point: he either should not use `WHERE` or should not expect that some magic "equal-to-anything" value exists

Answer (score 0):

You could use `1=1`

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE 1=1 AND bar=$bar
```

Comment: `WHERE 1` would suffice.